# Flex View Component to bind to generic object using reflection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, data-binding, reflection

Does there exist a Flex view component that you could just pass it a custom object with all public fields/properties that it could reflect over and produce a basic UI view using flex components.

Is it possible to use something like the [Spark DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html) with one item laid out vertically.

It would only have to support:

- TextField view of primitives (String, Number, Boolean)
- Sub view for Objects (recursively reflect sub objects)
- List component to view Arrays/Dictionaries

For example if you had an object like this:

```
public class CustomerData {

    public var customerName:String;
    public var addresses:Vector.<Address>;  

}

public class Address {
   public var street:String;
   public var houseNumber:Number;
   public var zipcode : String;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for.  Do you want something that will generate your UI dynamically at runtime based on some arbitrary object you send in?

Comment: I want a quick and dirty way to do like a "toString()" on an object but have it map to Flex user interface.

Comment: But, toString has nothing to do w/ a user interface.  I think I still don't get it.

Comment: I want a UI visualization of any custom defined Object, so we can get a skeletal view of the data we're modeling as we build up those data models.

Comment: I'll stop asking for clarification now.  Maybe someone else will understand better than I.

Comment: I think that what Dougnukem wants is some mechanism that would represent any given object as a set of visual components, one for every field of an object. So the sample `Address` class would be represented as 3 `TextFields` - one for street, one for houseNumber and one for zipCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like Kap Inspect: http://lab.kapit.fr/display/kapinspect/Kap+Inspect

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see what's what in your application, look at [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/).

Answer (score 0):

ObjectUtil might also do the trick.

```
ObjectUtil.toString(obj)
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html